# How many instances?

Tags: java, instances

I am having this Saturday a Java Exam, and I got on a website a question that I think that the solution is wrong:

Find below the question :

How many MarkList instances are created in memory at runtime?

```
public class MarkList {

    int num;

    public static void graceMarks(MarkList objet4){
        objet4.num += 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MarkList obj1 = new MarkList();
        MarkList obj2 = obj1;
        MarkList obj3 = null;
        obj2.num = 60;
        graceMarks(obj2);

    }

}
```

That website says that: it is created 3 instances at runtime.

I think it creates one instance.

Can you please give your point of view?

Comment: I'm like 99% sure the website is wrong.  I think only one instance is created.

Comment: maybe exam sites with `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` should be avoided

Comment: I wonder: are you sure the website says "objects?"  Does it ask how many references are created?  Because there are three references to the same object.

Comment: Here you have the site: http://www.aiotestking.com/oracle/how-many-marklist-instances-are-created-in-memory-at-runtime/

Answer (score 7):

You're correct. Only **one** instance is created, but it is referenced three times.

The instance is created here:

```
MarkList obj1 = new MarkList();
```

And referenced by `obj1`:

```
MarkList obj1 = new MarkList();
```

`obj2`:

```
MarkList obj2 = obj1;
```

And `objet4`

```
graceMarks(obj2);
```

Comment: There are three references created.  The third is "object4" parameter when the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Since the keyword `new`, marking the call of a constructor, is only seen ONCE in the example code and the position of the constructor call is not inside a loop or a method which is called multiple times, it is safe to say that only **ONE instance** is created.

Answer (score 1):

```
    MarkList obj1 = new MarkList();
    MarkList obj2 = obj1;
    MarkList obj3 = null;
```

is equivalent to the following C code roughly:

```
    MarkList* obj1 = (MarkList*)malloc(sizeof(MarkList));
    MarkList* obj2 = obj1;
    MarkList* obj3 = null;
```

As you can see, you allocate only one, and you get a pointer for it. Then you just make a second variable that stores a pointer, and that pointer points to the instance you allocated above.

Which means that there is only one instance.

EDIT: and in the method call,

```
void graceMarks(MarkList* objet4){
    (*objet4).num += 10;
}
```

So that's still dereferencing the pointer and therefore is still the same instance as you provided it.

Answer (score 0):

Only **1**.

Objects in `Java` can only be instantiated with the new operator. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Which is only used *once* and at `obj2` and `obj3` they are references to the pointer that is returned by the `new` operator

Answer (score 0):

At run-time instance is created via only `new` operator else other will be referenced. 
So **one** instance is created.